# Checked не переключает стили

Tags: css

```css
#links_custom>input#check{
    display: none;
}

label>span{
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    width:19px;
    height:19px;
    margin:-1px 4px 0 0;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background:url(http://i6.pixs.ru/storage/9/7/2/checkboxpn_1769852_29164972.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position-y: 19px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
label>input[type=checkbox]:checked + label>span {
    background:url(http://i6.pixs.ru/storage/9/7/2/checkboxpn_1769852_29164972.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position-y: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="links" id="links_custom">
        <label for="check">
            <input id="check" type="checkbox">
            <span></span>
        </label>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
#links_custom > input#check {
  display: none;
}

label > span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 19px;
  height: 19px;
  margin: -1px 4px 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: url(http://i6.pixs.ru/storage/9/7/2/checkboxpn_1769852_29164972.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position-y: 19px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

label > input[type=checkbox]:checked + span {
  background: url(http://i6.pixs.ru/storage/9/7/2/checkboxpn_1769852_29164972.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position-y: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="links" id="links_custom">
  <label for="check">
    <input id="check" type="checkbox">
    <span></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: так не переключает же и ваш!

Comment: @Proshka теперь переключает

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете `input` вынести за пределы `label`.

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label>span {
    background:url(http://i6.pixs.ru/storage/9/7/2/checkboxpn_1769852_29164972.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position-y: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="links" id="links_custom">
        <input id="check" type="checkbox">
        <label for="check">                
            <span></span>
        </label>
    </div>
```

Comment: вопрос не в этом. Вопрос: почему checked не переключает стили? Более того, мне нужен инпут внутри лэйбла

Comment: label>input[type=checkbox]:checked + label>span - написав этот код, вы подразумеваете, что в label после input рядом у вас стоит еще один label в котором находится span над которым и должны производиться действия. В разметке у вас такого нету, поэтому и не переключает.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Comment: Пожалуйста) В следующий раз, попробуйте задавать более развернутые вопросы.

Comment: В вашем css указано что после инпута должен идти label с вложенным span, а в разметке после инпута идет просто span ,исправьте как указал Yuri : label > input[type=checkbox]:checked + span

Comment: Соответственно в разметке после input у меня идет label со вложенным span) Я лишь показал другой способ реализации, который работает.